# Javscript Switch expression - How can it be made case insensitive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement, case-insensitive

I have two geojson files with the same key/labels but have different cases:
`feature.properties.STATUS` and `feature.properties.status`

I wish to test both file's label's values with a single switch statement:

```
    function PathStyle(feature) {
        switch (feature.properties.STATUS) {
            case "FP": 
                return {color: 'blue'}; 
            case "BR": 
                return {color: 'green'};
                etc...
```

This will only produce the expected results for the capitalized STATUS  values.

I've tried the `.toLowerCase()` method in various way, but with no success. ie:

```
    function PathStyle(feature) {
     var str = "feature.properties.STATUS";
     var strLC = str.toLowerCase();
      console.log(strLC);
        switch (strLC) {
        etc...
```

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: `switch (feature.properties.STATUS ?? feature.properties.status)`

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Is the problem that the property name varies between "STATUS" and "status", or is the problem that the *value* of the property is sometimes "FP" and other times "fp"?

Comment: @Barmar Sounds like they want to test both in the same `switch`, not whichever is not null/undefined.

Comment: Of course, there's no way for a `switch` to do two comparisons at once.

Comment: @HereticMonkey To me it sounds like some files use `STATUS`, others use `status`. They want to test whichever exists.

Comment: "two files ... but different cases"

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, and? One file has `feature: { properties: { STATUS: { FR: "whatever" } } }` the other has `feature: { properties: { status: { FR: "whichever" } } }` Your solution will always return the `STATUS` choice. But I could be wrong. Hard to say with a silent OP...

Comment: Please [edit] your question to also show the code where you are calling `PathStyle()` with the two different files

Comment: The comments section in SO definitely requires a down arrow option.

It's disappointing to see my question marked down due to some failing to read diligently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the null coalescing operator to try both `STATUS` and `status`, whichever actually exists.

```
    function PathStyle(feature) {
        switch (feature.properties.STATUS ?? feature.properties.status) {
            case "FP": 
                return {color: 'blue'}; 
            case "BR": 
                return {color: 'green'};
                etc...
```